# What does the `maximum error` field in `sudo dmidecode -t 22` mean

Tags: battery, dmidecode

When I do `sudo dmidecode -t 22` to get some information about my battery there is a field called `maximum error`

For my new battery `maximum error` is `15  %` (cheap replacement from a web store) for my old one (original DELL battery) `maximum error` is `0%`.

What does the term `maximum error` mean in this context and how can one interpret the `15 %`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [DTMF SMBIOS documentation](http://dmtf.org/standards/smbios) (p.97 of version 2.8.0):

> Maximum error (as a percentage in the range 0
>   to 100) in the Watt-hour data reported by the
>   battery, indicating an upper bound on how much
>   additional energy the battery might have above
>   the energy it reports having

So your DELL battery seems to have been more exact in reporting (or at least indicating it thought it was).